# Terraform: Is it possible to connect multiple github organizations?

Tags: github, terraform

I am trying to use terraform github provider (check [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs)) to add secrets to repos from multiple github organisations?

- From the github module help document, I don't think it is possible. Am I right?
- If this module didn't support this feature, is there another recommended?

Thank you!

Thank you!

Comment: What does "connect multiple organisation" mean?

Comment: Just edited, meaning connect repos from different github organisations.

Comment: What does "connecting repos" mean? I am still unsure what terraform has to do with it.

Comment: @luk2302 sorry, I just want to add secrets to repos which are from different organisations.

Comment: Since terraform is a solver that interfaces with APIs, the right question is whether there are GitHub API calls that would accomplish what you want. Your goal is not 100% clear to me, so the answer to that is "I don't know" for the time being. If there is a way to do this using GitHub API calls, then the question is whether it is possible to replicate that in terraform. That depends on the implementation of the provider.

Comment: @SinanÜnür You are right, I edited the question to express.

Comment: To focus the question and eliminate guesswork, you may want to include what you would if there were only one organization.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as pointed out in the comments, but let me take a wild guess on what could that possibly mean.

If by "add secrets to repos from multiple github organisations" you mean work towards **multiple** repositories in different organisations in a **single** Terraform configuration, then...

The answer is YES. You can do that. Checkout the [alias feature of providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#alias-multiple-provider-configurations), in short you should be good with:

```
provider "github" {
  owner = "org1"
}
provider "github" {
  alias  = "secondary"
  owner = "org2"
}
```

and then you can explicitly point to a non-default provider like this:

```
resource "github_actions_secret" "example_secret" {
  provider = github.secondary
  repository = "some_repository_in_org2"
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought alias is only working for aws provider. I definitely give a try soon. Will update here afterwards.

Comment: No. `alias` is a Terraform generic feature. Only they took `aws` as an example in the docs.